# completion for alias gone?

Tags: alias, auto-completion

The good method for completion for alias in this web https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=733397.

Now in 16.04, seems rules changed.

I can not find apt(_apt) completion command. but ls is(_longopt) here and it can works. of course apt also not in /etc/bash_completion.d/.

```
▶ complete |grep apt
▶ complete |grep '\<ls\>'
complete -F _longopt ls
▶ complete |grep 'upstart'
complete -F _upstart_reload reload
complete -F _upstart_stop stop
complete -F _upstart_initctl initctl
complete -F _upstart_start start
complete -F _upstart_status status
complete -F _upstart_restart restart
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I return to other old version, and this works. according to the file /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt.

```
alias ai='sudo apt install'
alias ap='sudo apt purge'
alias au='sudo apt update && msg 列表已经刷新 || msg 刷新失败'
alias ag='sudo apt upgrade'
alias as='apt list'
alias aw='apt show'
alias aa='sudo apt autoremove'

_show_installed()
{
        local cur
        COMPREPLY=()
        cur=`_get_cword`
        COMPREPLY=( $( _xfunc dpkg _comp_dpkg_installed_packages $cur ) )
        return 0
}
_show_all()
{
        local cur
        COMPREPLY=()
        cur=`_get_cword`
        COMPREPLY=( $( apt-cache pkgnames $cur 2> /dev/null ) )
        return 0
}
complete -F _show_all $default aw ai as
complete -F _show_installed $default ap
```